# Artifact e Group - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria saber oque significa na prática os campos `Group` e `Artifact` na criação de projetos **spring** e se existe alguma boa prática para nomeá-los.

E por que o campo `Group` vem com o valor "padrão" de `com.*` ?

Comment: Isso é coisa do Maven, não do Spring. Em tese pode ter "qualquer coisa", a ideia é evitar conflitos de nomes com outros projetos ([veja aqui](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html) para mais detalhes). O groupId não precisa começar com `com.`, mas geralmente ele segue as mesmas [convenções de nomes de pacotes do Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/packages.html#7.7), que tradicionalmente usa o domínio do site ao contrário (ex: na minhaempresa.com.br eu uso os pacotes `br.com.minhaempresa`), pois isso diminui as chances de ter outro nome igual

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente estes campos são para documentação do seu projeto, serve como referencia para o maven, então se alguém for usar seu projeto como dependência o `Group` será o nome do seu pacote raiz e o `Artifact` é o nome do seu projeto. Segue um exemplo de dependência:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Na documentação do Spring tem a seguinte descrição:

> Group: project coordinates (id of the project’s group, as referred by the groupId attribute in Apache Maven). Also infers the root package name to use.

> Artifact: project coordinates (id of the artifact, as referred by the artifactId attribute in Apache Maven). Also infers the name of the project

Answer (score -3):

Na prática, group será o caminho do default package, normalmente, o padrão é o que seria a url da aplicação invertido, por exemplo, br.com.google. Artifact é o nome do artefato único que o projeto vai gerar que, por padrão, é um .jar

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).